# Inference on platform types after calling a member of the platform type

Tags: kotlin, type-inference, nullable

Consider the following piece of code:

```kotlin
val subDirectory = File("/path/to/some/dir")
val imageFiles = subDirectory.listFiles()
    ?.filter { it.isFile && it.extension.equals("jpg", ignoreCase = true) }
    ?: listOf()
```

The type of `imageFiles` is inferred to be `List<File!>` because `File.listFiles()` comes from the Java standard library and has no nullability annotations. However, I am calling members of `File` in the `filter` block which would throw a `NullPointerException` if the list were to contain `null` values. Therefore, my question is why the compiler does not infer this and still assumes that the list contains a platform type.

Comment: From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) `File.listFiles()` return value (ther arrya) maybe null, but if the array is not null, then all element should be `abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname`

Comment: I am aware of how `File.listFiles()` works and what it returns. I am only curious as to why the compiler does not smart-cast the platform type away.